# Let $E$ be an extension field of $F$, of dimension $n$. Is there an element of degree $n$ in $E$ over $F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In other words, does there exist any element in $E$ such that its minimal polynomial over $E$ is of degree $n$?

Comment: This must be a duplicate but I can't find a good target at the moment.  For now, I'll leave you with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4):

What you are asking is whether any finite field extension has a *primitive element*; that is, if $[E:F]=n$, does there exist an $a\in E$ such that $E=F(a)$.

To see that this is equivalent to what you are asking, note that if such an element exists, then its minimal polynomial must have degree $[F(a):F] = [E:F] = n$; conversely, if there is an $a$ with minimal polynomial of degree $n$, then $[E:F(a)][F(a):F] = [E:F]=n$, but $[F(a):F]=n$, and therefore $[E:F(a)]=1$ so $E=F(a)$.

Such an extension is called a *simple extension*.

The answer is that such an element does *not* always exist, but it exists in most standard situations.

The most common situation is separability.

> **Primitive Element Theorem** If $E$ is finite and separable over $F$, then $E/F$ is simple.

More generally, we have:

> **Theorem.** Let $E$ be a finite extension of $F$. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. The extension $E/F$ is simple.
> 2. There are only finitely many intermediate fields $L$, $F\subseteq L\subseteq E$.

You can find proofs of this in this site, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1880496/a-finite-extension-with-finitely-many-intermediate-fields-is-simple/1880534#1880534).

You can also find examples of finite extensions where it does *not* happen; they have to be inseparable, which means they have to be in characteristic $p$ and infinite fields. You can an example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276627/a-finite-field-extension-that-is-not-simple)

Comment: In particular, the Primitive Element Theorem holds if $F$ has characteristic zero; in particular in particular, it holds if $F$ is the rationals.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gerry!